# iOS UIWebView HTML/CSS/JavaScript Errors Log

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have a question about `UIWebView`.

I am loading `UIWebView` from **HTML string**:

```
[self.webview loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

Question: Is there a way to **detect and log** HTML/CSS/JavaScript errors related with `htmlString` content?

Comment: You can do something like this: http://phonegap-tips.com/articles/debugging-ios-phonegap-apps-with-safaris-web-inspector.html

Comment: What is your question? Explain Properly.

Comment: Question: Is there a way to LOG web view content errors?

Comment: @TomKortney  Use delegate method of UIWebView...       
- webView:didFailLoadWithError:

Answer (score 1):

The only way to see HTML/CSS/JS errors in UIWebView is using [Safari Web Inspector](https://developer.apple.com/library/iad/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html)